# How to use Cases to extract sublists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following values obtained from a table:

```
aa = 
  {{13, 7, True, 
      {{273.055, 414.11}, {257.245, 418.458}, {253.813, 391.}, {261.5, 391.}}}, 
   {62, 4, True, 
     {{280.225, 468.254}, {279.037, 456.367}, {288.92, 447.472}, {312.404, 455.601}, 
      {310.811, 463.884}}},
   {200, 10, True, 
     {{248.093, 456.364}, {222.27, 447.757}, {210.584, 425.845}, {210.352, 422.125}, 
      {224.754, 418.261}, {232.288, 416.826}, {234.489, 417.364}, {249.333, 424.079}, 
      {251.248,  446.1}, {249.51, 453.683}, {248.405, 456.043}}},
   {29, 6, True, 
      {{206.5, 420.244}, {202.047, 420.141}, {191.868,  389.605}, {206.5, 393.786}}}}
```

Now, I want to extract those points from the values. So that the values will be:

```
bb = 
  {{{273.055, 414.11}, {257.245, 418.458}, {253.813, 391.}, {261.5, 391.}}, 
   {{280.225, 468.254}, {279.037, 456.367}, {288.92, 447.472}, {312.404, 455.601}, 
    {310.811, 463.884}},
   {{248.093, 456.364}, {222.27, 447.757}, {210.584, 425.845}, {210.352, 422.125}, 
    {224.754, 418.261}, {232.288, 416.826}, {234.489, 417.364}, {249.333, 424.079}, 
    {251.248,  446.1}, {249.51, 453.683}, {248.405, 456.043}},
   {{206.5, 420.244}, {202.047, 420.141}, {191.868,  389.605}, {206.5, 393.786}}}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: `Cases[aa, {_, _, _, lists : {{_, _} ...}} :> lists] == bb`

Comment: Or `aa[[All,-1]]`.

Comment: `cc = DeleteCases[aa, Except[_List], {2}] // Map[First]`

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `Cases`, use `Last` and `Map`.

Last /@ aa == bb

> `True`

Answer (score 0):

If you are not performing any tests to see if the list contains `True` you can use a combination of `Part` and `Flatten`.

```
bb = Flatten[aa[[All, -1]], 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]